# XML File Downloading in Spring MVC

Tags: xml, spring, download

I need to download xml file through spring mvc and need my application to navigate to some another jsp page after successful download using ModelAndView. While downloading file I am getting error that

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Could you please help me regarding this.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/download",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView downloadXmlFile(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

   servletcontext context = request.getsession().getservletcontext()

    File downloadFile = new File("c:\\abc.xml");
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(downloadFile);

    // get MIME type of the file
    String mimeType = context.getMimeType(fullPath);
    if (mimeType == null) {
        // set to binary type if MIME mapping not found
        mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
    }
    System.out.println("MIME type: " + mimeType);

    // set content attributes for the response
    response.setContentType(mimeType);
    response.setContentLength((int) downloadFile.length());

    // set headers for the response
    String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
    String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"",
            downloadFile.getName());
    response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

    // get output stream of the response
    OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead = -1;

    // write bytes read from the input stream into the output stream
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    inputStream.close();
    outStream.close();

    return "Success";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Create a Pojo Class Employee

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Book implements Serializable {

String title;
int pages;
String isbn;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

@XmlElement
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public int getPages() {
    return pages;
}

@XmlElement
public void setPages(int pages) {
    this.pages = pages;
}

public String getIsbn() {
    return isbn;
}

@XmlElement
public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
}

}
```

> 2. Create a  Controller

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class SpringMVCController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadXML")
public void downloadXML(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, JAXBException {
    Book book = new Book();
    book.setTitle("Lord of the Rings");
    book.setIsbn("Abbbbbb112");
    book.setPages(400);

    try {

        response.setContentType("application/xml");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment; filename=somefile.xml");

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Book.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        // output pretty printed
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        // writing to a file
        /*ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(
                response.getOutputStream());*/
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(book, response.getOutputStream());
        // writing to console
        // jaxbMarshaller.marshal(book, System.out);
        response.flushBuffer();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   }

  }


    > 3. **Create a Jsp index.jsp**

 <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01    Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Spring MVC XML Download Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form action="downloadXML" method="post" id="downloadXML">
    <h3>Spring MVC XML Download Example</h3>
    <input id="submitId" type="submit" value="Downlaod XML">
</form:form>
</body>
</html>



    > # Header 1 # 4. Create web.xml 
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
 <listener-  class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
 </web-app>


> 5. Create dispatcher-servlet.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="com.javahonk.controller" />
 <mvc:annotation-driven/>    

</beans>
```

** Give base-package name**

When we are not using the response.flushBuffer() some time it doesn't write content

Comment: When we are not using the response.flushBuffer() some time it doesn't write content. I was facing issue of writing due to this. Also jaxbMarshaller.marshal(book, System.out); is used when you do not want to download a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't download and redirect at the same time. You already wrote to the output stream and closed it so Spring can't render a view.

You could mimic what many download sites do where the download link takes you to a "Your download is starting" page that then redirects to the download after a short delay, but those are bad design in my opinion. I always close the page immediately after the download starts and never read it.

Comment: Thanks takteek.. but in my application it is necessary for me to navigate to some another page to continue with another part of application in continuation. So what approach do i need to be follow in this case...

Comment: Can you just take them to the next page right before starting the download? Redirecting to a page after a download finishes is just not something that's done. I suppose it's technically possible to figure out when a download has finished but you would have to hook into the web server to monitor when the last chunk of the file has been sent to the client. And even then you only know that the file was sent, not that it was saved successfully by the user.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is inherent to HTTP, for a given request you can send only one response.

So, when you write `outStream.close();` in your code, it ensures that the response is fully sent and after that the response stream doesn't accept anything else.

This might make you think, that you can remove the statement which is closing hte stream, I would say **bad idea.**

I will post something which can help you with this.

Comment: Thanks dharam.. SO, in your opinion what i need to be done so that i can redirect to some other page. because in my application it is necessary to navigate to some other page.

Comment: As I already told you , this is quite not possible the plain way. You cannot send two responses for one request. If you want, probably you can use some AJAX to play this role. When you have your file downloaded or when you receive the response for file downloading, you can send another ajax request which gets a redirection response.